# I am looking for a SQL script to sync a table from db A to db B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am still learn SQL and I need to have table A sync'd to table B in a different DB. Does anyone have a script to do that or point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to replace table B in Database2 with table A in Database1? If so, you could just use import/export wizard of SQL Server or just Management Studio: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sql+server+copy+table+to+different+database

Comment: This question isnt clear, and there are many things similar to what you ask.

Comment: This is not a code writing service.  Do some research, give a couple things a try and then come back if you have a specific problem that you can't solve.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO current_DB.A
(SELECT * FROM another_DB.B)
```

Comment: so will "insert into" only add new records from B to A after the first run?